# What games are similar to Risk?

Tags: recommendations, risk

Are there any other board games that have similar game mechanics to **Risk**?

Comment: "Are there any other board games that have similar game mechanics to Risk?" In what way? Which mechanics are of most interest to you?

Answer (score 15):

I generally think of Axis and Allies as being like advanced Risk.  Also there are all of the different Risk clones, 2210, LoTR, Star Wars, Godstorm and others which introduce slight variants in maps and rules.  Of those I'd recommend 2210, but if you can handle the complexity, which isn't bad in the grand scheme, Axis and Allies is the way to go.

Comment: Once you get into the order and mindset of how to resolve turns, Axis and Allies isn't that complex. Although not a perfectly balanced game, it really is a lot of fun when playing with 3 or more players.

Comment: I'd argue Risk isn't that well balanced either - perhaps it's a good match ;)

Comment: @Powertieke: Bidding in Axis & Allies allows for a more balanced game. In short, each player writes down a bid as to how many IPCs (or extra troops or whatever) they'd want to be "compensated" in order to play the Axis powers. The person with the lowest bid becomes the Axis.

Comment: Risk is atrociously balanced and far too luck based for my tastes.  A&A is slightly more reproducible, balanced and complex and therefore in my mind a better game, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

[Diplomacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomacy_%28game%29) is a similar game in that its aim is to conquer other players land. However it removes the dice and the element of chance, replacing it with face to face negotiation (making it a much better game IMHO).

You can [play it online](http://webdiplomacy.net/) for a quick taster. There are also [lots](http://www.diplom.org/index.py) of [other](http://www.diplomacy-archive.com/resources/strategy.htm) web based learning resources.

Comment: Diplomacy is really a very different game from Risk.  It's (to borrow an expression about poker) a people game played with a board and rules rather than a board and rules game played with people.

Answer (score 9):

[Shogun](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/20551/shogun) is another similar game. The combat is different in this game (you are not using dice at all) but gathering resources and conquering other provinces (which act like countries in Risk) has the same basic principles.

Comment: +1 for reminding me to dig my Shogun box out of the loft. I seem to remember there was a semi-decent PC conversion (*spit*) a few years back.

Comment: @Jon Hadley If I'm thinking about the same game as you are (Shogun: Total War), I don't think that game shares anything but title with the board game.

Comment: I thought it at least had the board game mechanic as an option to move your troops, but now you mention it, I do remember that it was more of a battle simulator than anything else.

Comment: @RaYell There are at least 4 different Shogun games - The one published by Queen Games looks like risk with cubes, but is a civ-game in play. The Milton-bradley one, renamed Samurai Swords, uses d10's and is really an Axis and Allies variant more than a risk variant. Neither of which is the same as Shogun: Total War.

Answer (score 5):

I really like [Risk 2210 A.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_2210_A.D.).  Basically a faster, more Aggressive risk (also more luck and less strategy, but this does not take away from the fun of nuking a continent :))

[Quest for the Dragonlords](http://www.questforthedragonlords.com/aboutthegame.html) also plays a little like risk, but, to be honest, fails miserably at being any fun to play.

Answer (score 4):

**History of the World** is played much like **Risk**.  There are 7 epochs.  During each epoch a player takes control of a different empire from the past.  They expand and conquer as much as they can (this part plays out very similar to Risk).  Next epoch they play a new vibrant empire.

Scoring is based on area control at the end of each player's turn.

Last year a new edition was released called, **A Brief History of the World** which is supposed to play to completion quicker.  I haven't yet tried it.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Dust](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/29109/dust), which is set in an alternate World War II. There you have mechs and tanks, submarines and destroyers, bombers and fighters. New additions also include character-based powers, fortified positions and capitals. Unlike vanilla RISK, it uses a VP track to determine victory.

One of the interesting part of the combat is that tanks soak damage before mechs, fighters soak damage before bombers and destroyers soak damage before submarines (If I recall correctly). Mechs, Bombers and Submarines provide more offense in the game

The official site for the game is [here](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite.asp?eidm=1).

Answer (score 4):

How about Twilight Imperium. We always play and when I explain to someone who is not into the scene what it is I always end up saying:"Ok, do you know Risk? Well it's like that but more complicated".

But I guess there are loads of game that then qualify as advanced Risk :).

Comment: Awesome game, but absolutely nothing like Risk.

Comment: You build units and try to conquer territories by fighting using dice. Furthermore, everyone receives a secret objective which when completed will (help to) win the game. That pretty much describes Risk, but is also true for Twighlight Imperium right? But it's true that with that definition of "like Risk" there are a lot of games that qualify.

Comment: Base mechanics, like 'roll to hit' and Victory Points allready make it al very different beast. But I agree that more people should play this game.

Answer (score 3):

[Ozymandia](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/18012/ozymandia) is simultaneous Risk, simplified to its essence.

Answer (score 3):

I used to play [Samurai Swords](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/221/samurai-swords) (also known as Shogun) as a kid. It's a lot like Risk, with several unit types, more complex battles, and more territories. It takes forever though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there are various Risk variants that use exactly the same rules and mechanics, but on a different board. I've got the Lord of the Rings and Star Wars variants, and there are [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_%28game%29#Official_licensed_Risk_games). As far as I can tell (from the LOTR and Star Wars verions) they normally/often have some extra (and optional) themed rule and unit variations, which, combined with the new map topology, can keep it interesting if you're bored of classic Risk.